# setting status of gtalk through android application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i change the status of my Gtalk or Gmail in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980298/how-can-i-change-the-status-of-my-gtalk-or-gmail-in-android)

I have an android application working right now. 
I would like to add a new feature in that -chat status.
I expect it to be working like this: when I set status to available or invisible, it should set my gtalk status to the same.
Is that possible in any way?