# How can i change the status of my Gtalk or Gmail in Android?

Tags: android

Using my application, i want to change the status of my gmail or gtalk. How can i change it?
Is there any sample code??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Want to change status of Gmail and its in your application?

Comment: Not in my application. Using my application i want to change the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Smack API](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/) for Android :

```
// Create the presence object with default availability 
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);

// Set the status message
presence.setStatus("Lame status is lame");

// Set the highest priority
presence.setPriority(24);

// Set available presence mode
presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);

// Send the presence packet through the connection
connection.sendPacket(presence);
```

Comment: So it means, from my application, at first i have to get connection with gmail id or gtalk. Then using Presence, i can change the status.

Comment: can we do this using Accounts and Account Manager class?  Because i can get the gmail id using this.                                       Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");      String myMailId = accounts[0].toString();

Comment: You can get the [password too](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getPassword(android.accounts.Account)).

Comment: password i can get. But can i set the status using this Account Manager?

Comment: I can't see anything of that sort in the documentation. So no.